# Equation for constructing the mate of the neckline and shoulder bevel

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image: Neckline construction]

I have a following neckline construction figure.

1. **ABC** - a right-angles triangle;
2. Bold lines are known values but all others are unknown;
3. **CD** = **L**; **AC** = **AD** + **DC**;
4. **A** - it's a center point of **S** arc; **AB** = **AD** - radius of **S**;
5. The arc **S** touches the side **AC** at right angle;
6. **L** and **S** are known.

***I have to find one from AB or BC or both.***

Experimentally, I manage to find the required BC value for the given S and L, and I feel that such a system has at least one solution, because if the BC value is incorrect, the picture is distorted.

But unfortunately I can't build myself to find the correct equation. I ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\measuredangle A=\theta$ (in radians as usual), then we have the arc $S$ giving
$$
S=AB\cdot\theta
$$
i.e.
$$
AB=AD=S/\theta
$$
Now you know the side $AB=S/\theta$ and the hypotenuse $AC=L+S/\theta$ making the angle $\theta$, so
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{S}{L\theta+S}
$$
which you can solve numerically for $\theta$, then you have $AB=S/\theta$ and $BC=AC\sin\theta=(L+S/\theta)\sin\theta$.

Comment: Nice work ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You are right, but I'm confused because θ is unknown ... hmm, I see ... I thought to get away from numerical methods.
Is it possible in this case?

Comment: @KoViMa No, it is not possible without numerical methods for general L/S.